# Javascript init function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three aspx pages that I wanted to share the same JS file each has its own init function.

Is there a better way to do this?

ASPX Page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ReimbursementDrug.init()
    });
</script>
```

JS Page

```
var ReimbursementProgram  = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            GetAllReimbursement();
        }
    }
}();

var ReimbursementAsset = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            GetAllAsset();
        }
    }
}();

var ReimbursementDrug = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {
            GetAllDrug();
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: Why not just add that code to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an element on those pages an unique id or class and apply a selector in the .js file.

```
$('.ReimbursementDrugClass').each(function () {
    ReimbursementDrug.init();
});
```

Or

```
if ($('#ReimbursementDrugID').length) {
    ReimbursementDrug.init();
}
```